# If string == "sting text" return int

Tags: java, string, int

I am trying to return an integer if particular string is true. (For this I do not want to use an array).

```
   public String calcNextDay()
  {
     if (day == "Sunday"){
      return 0; // If day is Sunday return 0
     }else if (day == "Monday"){
      return 1; // If Day is Monday return 1
     }else if (day == "Tuesday"){
       return 2; // If day is tuesday return 2
     }else if(day == "Wednesday"){
       return 3; // If day is Wednesday return 3
     }else if(day == "Thursday"){
        return 4;// If day is Thursday return 4
     }else if (day == "Friday"){
         return 5;// If day is Friday return 5
     }else if(day == "Saturday"){
        return 6;// if day is Saturday return 6
          }
          }
```

I have also tried this, but am getting an error with the return dayValue stating it can not be converted to String (even though I do not want to turn it to a string)

```
   public String calcNextDay()
  {
     int dayValue = 0;
     if (day == "Sunday"){
     dayValue = 0; // If day is Sunday return 0
     }else if (day == "Monday"){
     dayValue =1; // If Day is Monday return 1
     }
     return dayValue;
     }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Based on the comments I changed some code to

```
Public String calcNextDay()
  {
     int dayValue = 0;
     if (day.equals("Sunday")){
        dayValue = 0;
     }else if (day.equals("Monday")){
        dayValue = 1;
     }else if (day.equals("Tuesday")){
        dayValue = 2;

     }return dayValue;
          }
```

error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
                    }return dayValue;

Thank you, I got passed that problem and then I get to the error
Day.java:178: error: non-static variable dayValue cannot be referenced from a static context
         System.out.println("Your day is stored as " + testday.setDay() + dayValue);
                                                                          ^
1 error

My main() is a static, but my dayValue is not

Comment: you are returning `dayValue` which is an int, however `calcNextDay()` is declared as returning a `String`. Try this: `return Integer.toString(dayValue)`, or change the declaration to `public int calcNextDay()`

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate per se, but we don't know the type of `day` - from your errors, it leads me to believe that it's an `int` and not a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

All the string comparisons are wrong, in Java they must be done like this:

```
if (day.equals("Sunday"))
```

In other words, use `equals()` for testing equality, instead of `==`. Even better, it's a good practice to put the literal value first, in case the other value is `null`. This is what I mean:

```
if ("Sunday".equals(day))
```

And also, you are trying to return an `int` inside a function that specifies the return type as `String`, so change this:

```
   public String calcNextDay()
```

… to this:

```
   public int calcNextDay()
```

Comment: OK I changed it to that
  public String calcNextDay()
      {
         int dayValue = 0;
         if (day.equals("Sunday")){
            dayValue = 0;
         }else if (day.equals("Monday")){
            dayValue = 1;
         }else if (day.equals("Tuesday")){
            dayValue = 2;
                    
         }return dayValue;
              }
But I get error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
                    }return dayValue;

Comment: @MichaelLetendre as stated above: you _must_ change the method's return type to `int`, a number is not a `String`!

Comment: Thanks, I just found that, I did not see that you edited the answer by thanks I just found that and it helped

Answer (score 0):

In Java the strings are not compared with ==. **The correct way is to use method `equals`.**

```
if ("Sunday".equals(day))
```

For safety compare using ["Yoda convention"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions): the comparison will not fail even if day is null.

As for returning integer, using a lot of `if else` if not the best practice either. There are better ways to do it:

- Use switch statement 

  `switch (day) {
      case "Monday" : return 0;
      case "Tuseday": return 1;
      ...
   }`
- Create an array with day names and search for specific day in array. Return an index of the item found

Also, since you're returning `int`, your function's result type should be also `int`